# How to build a table with jQuery datatables with row child

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I'm using jQuery datatable with Ajax. Server with Laravel returns a JSON with the format:

```
{
"draw":0,
"recordsTotal":201
,"recordsFiltered":201,
"data":[{
"id":"1",
"numsocio":"1",
"identificacion":"9999999999",
"nombre":"Anna,
"apellidos":"Desclau", ........ etc
```

And I want to build a table like this (3 rows sample)

[image: table]

I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#socios_datatable').DataTable({
        ajax: '{{ route('socios.datatable') }}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'foto' },
            { data: 'nombre' },
            { ... }    
        ]
    });
});
```

And I've been testing with the info post in http://www.cscc.edu/_resources/app-data/datatables/examples/api/row_details.html but I don't get it to make it work. How to build easily a row with 2 subrows? I see that jQuery datatables is perfect for one row with several columns but for more complex rows is difficult.

May anybody help me?

Comment: you forgot to add this. `$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );`

Comment: ensenia mas code si quieries mas ayuda. (show more code if you want more help)

Comment: I dont want to open or close rows... I just want to do like a colspan

Comment: @WebAppDeveloperFreelance, You cant use colspans in dataTables at all, that would break he entire logic with sortable columns.

Comment: @davidkonrad, there is a workaround for colspan functionality, if sorting can be disabled.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, You are a hero if you produce an answer for this ☺☺☺, seems like there really need a good answer to that! :)

Comment: @davidkonrad, I will try to produce an answer, it just requires some time create a working example.

Comment: @davidkonrad, finally got some time to produce an article about it and the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using [Child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) for showing extra information.

Unfortunately `ROWSPAN` and `COLSPAN` attributes are not officially supported in table body by jQuery DataTables.

However, there is a workaround. It has some limitations though, you won't be able to use most of the DataTables extensions and searching/sorting need to either be disabled and adjusted to work correctly.

It is possible to emulate `ROWSPAN` attribute using [RowsGroup](https://github.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup) plug-in, see [jQuery DataTables: ROWSPAN in table body TBODY](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-rowspan-in-table-body-tbody/) article for more details.

It is possible to emulate `COLSPAN` attribute using a trick with hidden cells, see [jQuery DataTables: COLSPAN in table body TBODY](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-colspan-in-table-body-tbody/) article for more details.

It is possible to group cells both vertically and horizontally simultaneously if we combine both workarounds described above.

For example, sample code for your scenario with data received via Ajax could look like:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'ajax': 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/pr6dp',
   'columnDefs': [
      {
         'targets': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         'orderable': false,
         'searchable': false
      }
   ],
   'rowsGroup': [0],
   'createdRow': function(row, data, dataIndex){
      // Use empty value in the "Office" column
      // as an indication that grouping with COLSPAN is needed
      if(data[2] === ''){
         // Add COLSPAN attribute
         $('td:eq(1)', row).attr('colspan', 5);

         // Hide required number of columns
         // next to the cell with COLSPAN attribute
         $('td:eq(2)', row).css('display', 'none');
         $('td:eq(3)', row).css('display', 'none');
         $('td:eq(4)', row).css('display', 'none');
         $('td:eq(5)', row).css('display', 'none');
      }
   }      
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/efuwgg1L/) for code and demonstration.

See [jQuery DataTables: COLSPAN in table body TBODY - COLSPAN and ROWSPAN](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-colspan-in-table-body-tbody/) article for more details.

Comment: Nice job!!! :) But with all respect, it is merely a cosmetic solution, you have to provide double JSON for each row, and after the cosmetic styling you *could* insert for example a <table> in code. I guess it would not be so hard to have a nested JSON with child content to insert as details / extra row. I think it is really good if you would like to place a header above each row.  BTW, see your point with multiple links to the same URL with different anchor texts, but I *believe* the first anchor text is the one that actually have importance / gives your site keyword value.

Comment: @davidkonrad, it could be hard to insert a second row with details and be compatible with RowsGroup plug-in. My solution possibly have limited use for plain tables that need jQuery DataTables support.